# Mouse inputs make the picture drag and copy rather than just drag

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

Here is an example of what it looks like when I drag a picture with the mouse
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQDU.jpg

And here is the code for it.
When I load the project on the desktop application, the picture displays perfectly in the middle, but when I move it with the mouse it drags itself like in Windows xp.

```
public class SlingshotSteve implements ApplicationListener{

private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture texture;
private Sprite sprite;


@Override
public void create() { 
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280, 720);     

    batch = new SpriteBatch();


    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);

    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    sprite.setOrigin(0,0);
    sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2,-sprite.getHeight()/2);


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    texture.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {  
    // Make the background color Black
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Mouse imput        
    if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
        sprite.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX() - sprite.getWidth()/2,
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY() - sprite.getHeight()/2);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.RIGHT)){
        sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 -sprite.getWidth()/2, 
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - sprite.getHeight()/2);
    }

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with libgdx, but that problem sounds like the screen is not clearing itself. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Clearing-the-screen

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but a new problem came up. When I try to drag it the picture moves itself in the upper right hand corner. So every time  I try to click, the picture duplicates itself in another place. It just duplicates once, not a million times.